# REST API How to retrieve the ID of a newly created file

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, json

Using the Sharepoint Online REST API I have successfully created a new file using a POST request -
`https://company.sharepoint.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyTitle')/Files/add(name='test.jpg',overwrite=true)`

Following the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) I'm now trying to update the file metadata -

> If you want to update a file's metadata, you have to construct an
>   endpoint that reaches the file as a list item.
>
> Construct an endpoint that looks like this: 
>   https://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(item id)

When creating the file the response I get back from the POST request is something like the following -

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "https://company.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'288441230-b910-4665-ae1d-a359b06c9af8')/files('2_QQs7Rb_UOV1fUNAJw1bJxTMrEZ5qlEmmNfyYNoND5ftgyx2P4lQ4dUdToJAvCF')",
            "uri": "https://company.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'288441230-b910-4665-ae1d-a359b06c9af8')/files('2_QQs7Rb_UOV1fUNAJw1bJxTMrEZ5qlEmmNfyYNoND5ftgyx2P4lQ4dUdToJAvCF')",
            "type": "MS.FileServices.File"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

My question is how do you retrieve the `item id` as obviously the urls here are different to the url required by update metadata method.

Comment: Check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662332/getting-item-id-after-rest-upload-to-sharepoint-2013-online-document-library - try adding ?$expand=ListItemAllFields to the request url when uploading the file.

Comment: Thanks Damjan. I did see that post earlier and tried adding the `$expand=ListItemAllFields` parameter to the post request but it doesn't seem to make any difference to the number of fields returned.

Comment: Is that all you get from SP Online? I'm using SP2013 on prem and get quite a bit more back in the "d" object. But I do also have to make another call to get the ID and from there I can then make a third call to set metadata.

Comment: To be fair there is a bit more data in the "d" object, I just didn't include it all. Nothing that references the id. However, that's reassuring if you also have to perform 3 separate requests to set the metadata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return the ID:

```
/siteURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/Items?$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'AdventureWorksBikesWithDetails.xlsx'&$select=Id
```

This will return:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "2ccf8662-1f02-4c57-b505-120e425660da",
                    "uri": "https://siteURL/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c8612335-fb7e-4edf-bf1d-b9186a8b987b')/Items(15)",
                    "etag": "\"2\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem"
                },
                "Id": 15,
                "ID": 15
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that works a treat. So to clarify there is no way to retrieve this during the initial post? It seems like creating a file and setting metadata is something that should be easier than making two separate calls.

Comment: Thanks for that. @ChrisEdgington, you don't need to do an extra call, just add `?$expand=ListItemAllFields&$select=Id` after the POST URL and the id will be included in the response.